# How can I open an iTunes radio station like Beats 1 with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

There does not appear to be a direct way to open an iTunes radio station like Beats 1 with AppleScript? Is there one that I'm missing? Is there a workaround? I'm using iTunes 12.2.

Comment: Normally you could try 'GUI Scripting' (Link: http://dougscripts.com/itunes/category/gui-scripting/), but I'm not sure if it will work because you have to click the play button which is not really in a menu.

Comment: GUI scripting isn't dependent on something being in a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. iTunes must be in windowed mode for GUI scripting to work unfortunately. The basic idea is: tell iTunes to activate, check for the "radio" tab, when it appears, click on it, then do the same thing for the "Listen Now" button for Beats 1 radio:

```
tell application "iTunes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "iTunes"
        repeat while (radio button "Radio" of radio group 2 exists) is false
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        click radio button "Radio" of radio group 2
        repeat while (button "Listen Now" of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 2 exists) is false
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        click button "Listen Now" of group 2 of group 1 of group 1 of UI element 1 of scroll area 2
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Excellent. Is there a friendly way to inspect the UI elements?

Comment: Yep. You can crawl the view hierarchy by using something like `tell application "System Events" to get buttons of window 1 of application "iTunes"` then if you don't find what you're looking for, try `tell application "System Events" to get buttons of UI elements of window 1 of application "iTunes"` and if that doesn't work, keep adding "of UI elements" right after buttons, and eventually you'll find the button you're looking for. That's how I made this script.

Comment: Also, it helps to download Xcode and use "Accessibility Inspector" buried within Xcode's bundle at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility Inspector.app". Get Xcode from the App Store and go there with the Finder by pushing "⌘ + shift + g" and entering that path. It attempts to show you the UI hierarchy needed to get to any UI element you move your mouse over, but it isn't always correct, and doesn't really give you enough information. I use it to determine what "kind" of UI element I'm looking for, which tells me what to put after "get" when I crawl the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and traverse the iTunes GUI, use Safari and AppleScript to launch iTunes and play Beats 1. The trick is to use Apple's Beats web page at https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/listen-in-apple-music/idra.978194965.

```
set theClassName to "action listen-in-itunes"
set elementNum to 0

tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/listen-in-apple-music/idra.978194965"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementNum & "].click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Note: For this to work, you will need to enable Allow JavaScript from Apple Events in Safari's Develop menu.

This helped: http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the web page that launches Beats One in iTunes and found the URL that gets launched when the button is clicked. I can now launch Beats One with a one-liner AppleScript:

```
open location "itmss://itunes.apple.com/us/station/listen-in-apple-music/idra.978194965?cmd=AddStation"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this query resolved anyway I give my modest solution:
I use Alfred , although automator is the same .
I created a "alt + Ienter image description here " hotkey to open a url that copied from iTunes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeKTa.jpg